# iTunes Connect app release confusion

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

This will be 1st first app. In my iTunes Connect account my app is in Prepare For Submission mode now. When I upload a project build to iTunes Connect and click Submit For Review, lets say App Store reviews it and it goes well, do the app reviewers then automatically put my app in App Store if I clicked on Automatically Release This Version under version release? Or if I have it in Manually Release this version then my app goes to Ready For Sale mode and it doesn't get released to app store and I get promo codes so I can give to app reviewers? This is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the new iTunes Connect, you can set "Manually release this version" even on the first version of the app, not just updates like the old version of iTC.

[image: Manually release this version]

Once the app is approved, you can create promo codes and send them to reviewers before you actually release the app to the public. Be aware however, that the promo codes are tied to the version they are created for. Ie, if you submit 1.0, and it's approved, and then generate a promo code for it. That promo code will download version 1.0 for the user, even if you later submit 1.1 and have it approved. This is important for reviewers, since you want them on the newest version. So you'd need to reissue new codes if you submit an update. Once the app is released to the public, obviously those people will get the update as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically release means just that, it will be released publicly if/when it is approved.

Manually means it still goes through the process of review but is then down to your to release.

Promo codes can be given at any time if your app is paid for, once it has been approved. If you mean TestFlight then I believe that can only be done with builds that have not been reviewed yet.

Comment: I have a free app with ads. I was thinking of giving promo codes to review sites so I can get some people knowing about my app before it's released in app store. I didn't think promo codes are only used for paid apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's correct, automatically release means that upon your app being reviewed and accepted, your app will be released into the App Store of the countries that you have selected. Please note this can sometimes take up to a couple of hours to become available in all stores. Also if you have in app purchases, these can also take some time to be released.

If you select manually release then you will have to go into iTunes Connect and release the app yourself.

If you only want the app to be available to a select few people then I would suggest using Test Flight to distribute your app to those people as once your app is released then anyone can download it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you set the `"version release"` as `"Automatic"`, then the app will be published on the appstore as soon as it is approved by the iTunes.
2. If you set the `"version release"` as `"Manual"`, then after the app is approved it is published only when you release it yourself.

> *[Note: Make sure that you set the "Availability date" in the "Pricing tab" in the future when setting the "version release" to "Manual". You
>   can change this date whenever you want to even when the app is
>   approved]*

Comment: So the day I set the release to Manual I also have to set an availability date OR do I first set the version to manual, get it reviewed by Apple and then after they review it and it says "Pending Developer Release", only then do I choose availability date in pricing tab?

Comment: It is advised by apple to "set the app’s availability date to an arbitrary date in the future. When the app is approved by Apple, you can decide more precisely when you want the app to appear on the store." (Link: http://apple.co/1DciLaa)